# GPDB initialization

Tags: python, greenplum

i am trying to initialize greenplum DB , but i got the following error `Check your installation; "postgres -V" may have more information.
cat: /mnt/disk4/greenplum/data/primary/gpseg0.initdb: No such file or directory
20180408:12:19:34:006361 gpcreateseg.sh:datanode3:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Start Function BACKOUT_COMMAND
20180408:12:19:34:006361 gpcreateseg.sh:datanode3:gpadmin-[INFO]:-End Function BACKOUT_COMMAND
20180408:12:19:34:006361 gpcreateseg.sh:datanode3:gpadmin-[INFO]:-Start Function BACKOUT_COMMAND
20180408:12:19:34:006361 gpcreateseg.sh:datanode3:gpadmin-[INFO]:-End Function BACKOUT_COMMAND
20180408:12:19:34:006361 gpcreateseg.sh:datanode3:gpadmin-[FATAL][0]:-Failed to start segment instance database datanode1 /mnt/disk4/greenplum/data/primary/gpseg0`

Comment: Does this path exist?  /mnt/disk4/greenplum/data/primary/

Comment: yes i have handled this issue , after installed the gpdb on segment host , it look like there was a missing libraries , but now i got the following error when run gpstop command   gpstop
20180408:23:21:02:017614 gpstop:datanode3:root-[INFO]:-Starting gpstop with args: 
20180408:23:21:02:017614 gpstop:datanode3:root-[INFO]:-Gathering information and validating the environment...
20180408:23:21:02:017614 gpstop:datanode3:root-[ERROR]:-gpstop error: postmaster.pid file does not exist.  is Greenplum instance already stopped?

Comment: also on gpstate 20180408:23:21:48:017711 gpstate:datanode3:root-[INFO]:-Starting gpstate with args: 
20180408:23:21:48:017711 gpstate:datanode3:root-[INFO]:-local Greenplum Version: 'postgres (Greenplum Database) 5.7.0 build f7c6eb5-oss'
20180408:23:21:48:017711 gpstate:datanode3:root-[CRITICAL]:-gpstate failed. (Reason='could not connect to server: Connection refused

Comment: could you help me

Comment: Is the database still running? From the error message it looks like it's not. Also are you executing this as root or as gpadmin user?

Comment: as gpadmin user